# Pass Query string to cake style URL in cakephp and give ext of HTML

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-routing

**What I am trying to achieve:**

When user passes this:

```
/results?val=real&x=1&y=0
```

it should show:

```
/results/real.html?x=1&y=0
```

and from Action I should still be able to access `$this->request->query['val']` which should be equal to `real`

**What I have done so far?**

I am using CakePHP 2.4

```
Router::parseExtensions('html');

Router::connect('/results/:val', 
            array('controller'=>'Post','action'=>'results',
'?' => array('val'=>'[A-Za-z0-9]-_ +','x'=>'[0-9]+','y'=>'[0-9]+')));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just define the route as like below in your `routes.php` file.

```
Router::connect(
    '/results/:val', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'Post',
        'action' => 'results',
    ), 
    array(
        'pass' => array('val')
    )
);
```

You can set the params like the below in order to generate the link in the way you want.

```
echo Router::url(array(
    'controller' => 'Post',
    'action' => 'results',
    'val' => 'real',
    'ext' => 'html',
    '?'  => array('x' => '1', 'y' => '0')
));
```

Which displays: `results/real.html?x=1&y=0`

Comment: let me know if you have any query or concern keval sir @KarmicDice

Comment: Thanks @Anil however, I am posting a GET form... so do you advice that I take the parameters and then echo Router::url because URL will be formed automatically...

Comment: how can i make it complete, just advise me, so i can make it as completed

Comment: wait am playing around... hang in there... we have 6 days till it expires... so chill the f out...

Comment: ehm ... a very very very simple question: have you enabled the rewrite rules?

Comment: I did sir. @daniele_dll didn't work... now I am taking in the request queries and then redirecting user using $this->redirect() with URL formed as mentioned in the second block of code by the answer-er

Comment: Just wanted to share in this question the whole explanation of all the options we have when dealing with routing params. Found at @dereuromark blog http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/